# How to know that a user is granted with the necessary priviliges to act as the recovery catalog owner (Oracle 12c)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a database TRADES with few users and one of them is having the necessary privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query `USER_ROLE_PRIVS`. For example, my Scott user doesn't have that privilege (its name is **RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER**:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> select * from user_role_privs;

USERNAME                       GRANTED_ROLE                   ADM DEF OS_
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --- --- ---
SCOTT                          CONNECT                        NO  YES NO
SCOTT                          RESOURCE                       NO  YES NO

SQL>
```

But, if I grant it:

```
SQL> connect sys/pwd as sysdba;
Connected.
SQL> grant recovery_catalog_owner to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

and check again:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> select * From user_role_privs;

USERNAME                       GRANTED_ROLE                   ADM DEF OS_
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --- --- ---
SCOTT                          CONNECT                        NO  YES NO
SCOTT                          RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER         NO  NO  NO  --> here it is
SCOTT                          RESOURCE                       NO  YES NO
```

---

Aditionally, if you connect as a privileged user (such as `sys`) and wish to know which users were granted that role, then

```
SQL> select * from dba_role_privs where granted_role = 'RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER';

GRANTEE                        GRANTED_ROLE                   ADM DEF
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --- ---
SYS                            RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER         YES YES
SCOTT                          RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER         NO  NO

SQL>
```